# Find Record which should have at least one value defined for one parameters for each row

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, logic

I have below List ->

List address;

Employee

name,
age
company
Salary

```
Name                    Age             Company     Salary    
A                       21              comp_A       100        
A                       21              comp_A              
A                       21              comp_A          
B                       22              comp_B              
B                       22              comp_B       200        
C                       23              comp_C       300        
D                       24              comp_D          
E                       25              comp_E
```

I want those records in which for same name,age ,company I should have at least and only one salary defined.
Since this duplicate record represent to same employee  and they will must have a salary.

Appreciate the logic will fetch those record which met with this condition and also which does not met with the condition like the last tow rows for D/E employee does not have any value defined for Salary and 
I should get these value as well.

Comment: Too broad. Tried anything?

Comment: Please see my comments wrt Traian commemt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the list into a stream,remove duplicates and collect back into a new list.
You have 2 options with distinct(remove duplicate by all fields) and distinctByKey
(remove duplicate based on particular criteria or just some fields)

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-stream-distinct-examples/

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FindR {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Employee> l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("A",21,"comp_A",100.0));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("A",21,"comp_A",100.0));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("A",21,"comp_A",null));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("A",21,"comp_A",null));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("B",22,"comp_B",null));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("B",22,"comp_B",200.0));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("C",23,"comp_C",300.0));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("D",24,"comp_D",null));
    l.add(new FindR().new Employee("E",25,"comp_E",null));

    List<Employee> l_salaryNotNull = l.stream().filter(p->p.salary !=null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("_salalary defined_");
    l_salaryNotNull.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("_unique by name,age,company_");
    List<String> l_uByNAC = l.stream().map(p->p.name+":"+p.age+":"+p.company).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    //or remove first null values and then get keys
    //List<String> l_uByNAC = l.stream().filter(p->p.salary !=null).map(p->p.name+":"+p.age+":"+p.company).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    l_uByNAC.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    //eg: process first record 
    String aux[] = l_uByNAC.get(0).split(":");
    System.out.println("keys for search in initial list | name="+aux[0]+",age="+aux[1]+",company="+aux[2]);
}


public class Employee 
{
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public String company;
    public Double salary;
    public Employee(String n, Integer a,String c, Double s)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        company = c;
        salary = s;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "name:"+name+":age:"+age+":company:"+company+":salary:"+salary;
    }
}
}
//output
//_salalary defined_
//name:A:age:21:company:comp_A:salary:100.0
//name:A:age:21:company:comp_A:salary:100.0
//name:B:age:22:company:comp_B:salary:200.0
//name:C:age:23:company:comp_C:salary:300.0
//_unique by name,age,company_
//A:21:comp_A
//B:22:comp_B
//C:23:comp_C
//D:24:comp_D
//E:25:comp_E
//(first)key for search in initial list | name=A,age=21,company=comp_A
```

Comment: The problem is I need to check the duplicate on the basis of  name,age,company but I can have 10 duplicate records which have 5 such records which defines value for salary and 5 which does not define it so on what basis I am going to collect those records. While collecting I should have also the count of salary for each row if it has value for salary or not and when we end up with uniqueness I should have record with the count of salary defined for the row and then I can check if that unique row does have salary count 0 or not .Like in the same example I should get one A with 1 salary count

Comment: As far as i see one way is to use java8 stream since you have distinct method and grab what ever records you wanted based on whatever criteria (use predicates).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion , I got a path forward to get the distnict one based upon Name ,Age,Company.Any idea If in the same logic How Can I maintain the count of occurrence of Salary for each employee in the same logic using Java 8 only ?

Comment: I done something here, just take a look maybe it can help you. It's not perfect but you could work further on it.

Comment: Sure, you can track occurrences, but see where to store.Could use another field on compound object Employee (count) which you will compute latter.Maybe you could look also on groupBy in java8. Also if you put a counter on your records (1,2,3) then you could use a HashMap and could grab/link the records  based on counter (something like in db)